# Cannot access Web UI for Eaton UPS Network-MS card on 172.x.x.x network

Tags: networking, dhcp, ups

I have an Eaton 5PX1500RTN UPS with a Network-MS card installed and I could access the Web UI when I first set it up during initial testing on a 192.168.1.1/24 network.

I made sure that I used DHCP in the "Network" properties for the Eaton web card. Then I put the UPS on my actual network which has 172.x.x.x setup with a /16 subnet. But now I cannot access the Web UI for the Eaton UPS at all.

I could see that it received a DHCP address in my router -- but trying that IP, it just fails to connect and times out. I even tried setting a static IP for the UPS's MAC address in my router, but I still cannot get to the Web UI.

To double check if I had actually set the card up as DHCP -- I put it back on a 192.168.1.1/24 network and I could immediately get to the Web UI. Again made sure it is set to DHCP -- put it back on the 172.x.x.x network and yet again I couldn't access the Web UI.

What can I do so that the card will allow me to get into the Web UI on the 172 network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, in addition to switching the UPS off and then on again (which I had already tried), you also have to remove the plug from the wall socket. I let it sit overnight without plugging it in and then on switching on everything I was able to get to the WebUI of the UPS card on the 172 network.

Seems like the IP or the IP range gets cached somewhere -- even if you have selected DHCP assigned address. This seems like a bug -- a DHCP assigned address should be able to reset if you change it in the router and restart the DHCP server or the router

I hate issues like these.